# Set environment variable not working on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, environment-variables

I used this command to set environment variable but I don't know why it is not working

```
D:\Developing tools\apache-tomcat-platform\bin>setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\
Java\jdk1.7.0_51"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

D:\Developing tools\apache-tomcat-platform\bin>startup.bat
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

Comment: Have you restart your cmd window after setting the environment variables?

Comment: why not: set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\
Java\jdk1.7.0_51" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restarting the pc solve the problem :)